# Unable to add Classes to UWP apps

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am working with UWP apps. When I try to add a class, it is popping an error stating that: "The reference system could not be added to the project. This wizard will continue to run, but the resulting project  may not build properly".
When I click ok..The class loads, but when I tried to build it shows many errors.
I have run the Visual studio community 2015 update 2 repair also. It showed some errors. I have uploaded the screen shots of the errors. Please help me..

When I try to add a class:

[image]

After running the repair:

[image]

Comment: When was last time it was working for you? Was it working in Update1 and started failing right after Update2?

Comment: Yes..It worked in Update 1...and stopped working after installing update 2

Comment: update 3 is out. This might not exactly sound like a solution but can apply update 3 and report back if it helps resolve the problem.

Comment: Any update? Where you able to resolve the issue?